# WPF MVVM как привязать цвет кнопки

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть несколько кнопок и ListBox с некоторыми элементами.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы при выборе определенного элемента в листбоксе цвет кнопок менялся бы автоматом.Сделать надо в MVVM шаблоне...
Я понимаю, что тут надо делать привязку к выбранному элементу, но не понимаю как тут привязать цвет кнопки((сделать отдельное свойство у объекта элемента который в ListBox, допустим типа Enum сделать, и если у элемента в боксе энам1, то цвет кнопки становится красный, а если в боксе энам2, то цвет становится синий...не пойму как привязать именно цвет кнопки(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью триггера или конвертера. Триггер немного проще в исполнении и требует меньше кода. Я покажу на примере надписи на кнопке и видимости изображение, с цветом фона дела обстоят абсолютно так же.

В примере я использую простой VM-класс для элемента коллекции с двумя свойствами — надпись (string) и признак блокировки (bool). В главной VM коллекция этих элементов и простая команда для установки/снятия признака блокировки.

Разметка:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>

                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="lock.ico"
                           Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocked}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding LockCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Items/}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Lock"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items/IsLocked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Unlock"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Главное — помните, что явная установка значения свойства зависимости имеет более высокий приоритет перед значением, которое устанавливает триггер, поэтому исходный цвет устанавливайте не явно, а в стиле кнопки.

Получается вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]