# Где менять визуальное отображение компонентов View в патерне MVVM?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Приложение построено по MVVM-шаблону. У меня есть CheckBox, при состоянии `IsChecked = true` которого должно меняться свойство **Visibility** у **TextBlock**, а при состоянии `IsChecked = false` возвращаться в default состояние.

Как это реализовать в рамках этого патерна? Назначить обработчики событий у `MainWindow`?

Comment: С помощью триггера или конвертера

Comment: @АндрейNOP, триггера где вы имеете в виду? Сразу в определении элемента?

Comment: Да, в стиле элемента, стиль можно вынести в ресурсы чтоб не так громоздко было. Здесь пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834228/218063

Comment: Вот еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794510/218063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Самое простое это так, но можно, конечно же, сделать через команды на элементе CheckBox (его событие IsChecked), обрабатывать его в .cs, заводить дополнительные ненужные bool переменные